# Which Person of the Trinity is the Ancient of Days sitting on His throne?

Tags: nature-of-god, persons-of-the-trinity, words-of-jesus, names-of-god, god-the-father

**Accordring to Trinitarians who is this person with a form, sitting on His throne?**

Daniel 7:9-27
New King James Version
Vision of the Ancient of Days

> 9 “I watched till thrones were put in place, **And the Ancient of Days
> was seated**; His garment was white as snow, And the hair of His head
> was like pure wool. His throne was a fiery flame, Its wheels a burning
> fire; 10 A fiery stream issued And came forth from before Him. A
> thousand thousands ministered to Him; Ten thousand times ten thousand
> stood before Him. The court was seated, And the books were opened.
>
> 11 “I watched then because of the sound of the pompous words which the
> horn was speaking; I watched till the beast was slain, and its body
> destroyed and given to the burning flame. 12 As for the rest of the
> beasts, they had their dominion taken away, yet their lives were
> prolonged for a season and a time.
>
> 13 “I was watching in the night visions, And behold, One like the Son
> of Man, Coming with the clouds of heaven! He came to the Ancient of
> Days, And they brought Him near before Him. 14 Then to Him was given
> dominion and glory and a kingdom, That all peoples, nations, and
> languages should serve Him. His dominion is an everlasting dominion,
> Which shall not pass away, And His kingdom the one Which shall not be
> destroyed.

Comment: As a Trinitarian: The Ancient of Days is God the Father.

Comment: This question seems more like it would be a BHSE question. Scoping it to trinitarianism doesn't really change the interpretation, I don't think anyone would deny this is God the Father.

Comment: @LukeHill non trinitarians don’t use the term God the Father.

Comment: @Kris why not? It’s how Jesus identifies him.

Comment: @LukeHill where is that?

Comment: @Kris lots of places but John 5:17 for one.

Comment: @LukeHill of course YHWH is rightly called Father by Jesus and all of crested beings.   The title “God the Father” is a trinitarian one used to distinguish between the claimed three persons of the so called Godhead

Comment: @Kris but then that's my point. I'm just using it as a term to identify God, and that's what everyone thinks. The only distinction is just in terminology, not really theology per se. Everyone agrees there is a person who is identified as the Father, and this is the ancient of days. No one would say otherwise, so it is a BHSE question.

Comment: Lol not crested beings.  Created beings.

Comment: @LukeHill but Op is specific   Wants an answer from those who think father son and hs are all God

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152244/discussion-between-luke-hill-and-kris).

Answer (score 4):

### **The Ancient of Days is God the Father**

Daniel 7:13:

> 13 “In my vision at night I looked, and there before me was one like a son of man,[a] coming with the clouds of heaven. He approached the Ancient of Days and was led into his presence. 14 He was given authority, glory and sovereign power; all nations and peoples of every language worshiped him. His dominion is an everlasting dominion that will not pass away, and his kingdom is one that will never be destroyed. (ESV)

This closely mirrors Matthew 28:18:

> 18 And Jesus came and said to them, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. (ESV)

Further, consider the words of the Angel to Mary in Luke 1:

> 30 And the angel said to her, “Do not be afraid, Mary, for you have found favor with God. 31 And behold, you will conceive in your womb and bear a son, and you shall call his name Jesus. 32 He will be great and will be called the Son of hthe Most High. And the Lord God will give to him the throne of his father David, 33 and he will reign over the house of Jacob forever, and of his kingdom there will be no end.” (ESV)

So the person coming to the Ancient of Days is Christ. Clearly in Daniel 7 the Ancient of Days is someone Daniel is familiar with, for he doesn't question who the Ancient of Days is, but does question what the meaning of the vision of "the one like the son of man".

As we know, Christ sits at the right hand of the Father, in accord with the above text about Christ being given authority and dominion, as a "right hand man" would be:

> Who is to condemn? Christ Jesus is the one who died—more than that, who was raised—who is at the right hand of God, who indeed is interceding for us. (Romans 8:34)

As a last note, notice how the end of Daniel parallels the Book of Revelation and it becomes pretty clear who the Ancient of Days is.

> 23 “He gave me this explanation: ‘The fourth beast is a fourth kingdom that will appear on earth. It will be different from all the other kingdoms and will devour the whole earth, trampling it down and crushing it. 24 The ten horns are ten kings who will come from this kingdom. After them another king will arise, different from the earlier ones; he will subdue three kings. 25 He will speak against the Most High and oppress his holy people and try to change the set times and the laws. The holy people will be delivered into his hands for a time, times and half a time.26 “‘But the court will sit, and his power will be taken away and completely destroyed forever. 27 Then the sovereignty, power and greatness of all the kingdoms under heaven will be handed over to the holy people of the Most High. His kingdom will be an everlasting kingdom, and all rulers will worship and obey him.’28 “This is the end of the matter. I, Daniel, was deeply troubled by my thoughts, and my face turned pale, but I kept the matter to myself.”

In conclusion, the Ancient of Days is God the Father.

Comment: I am told here by trinitarians that God the Father has no form. NO image actually... God the Son is the image of God. So the trinity believes in 2 persons with distinct forms that both sit on thrones and yet they claim 1 God?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore I don’t understand your question - what do you mean by “form”? Are you referring to the platonic idea of form or something like “image”?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I mean.  The Father has a body and He sits on a Throne.  Many visions confirm this.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore I gave you two options - saying yes doesn’t help me narrow down what you’re saying.

Comment: I am using the word 'form' in the more classical sense which precedes Plato's theory.  And by image in this case I mean "able to be directly observed".  Do you think you will see the Father in heaven?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore https://www.newadvent.org/summa/5092.htm#article2